# Sum rows in a group, starting when a specific value occurs

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to accumulate the values of a column till the end of the group, though starting the addition when a specific value occurs in another column. I am only interested in the first instance of the specific value within a group. So if that value occurs again within the group, the addition column should continue to add the values. I know this sounds like a rather strange problem, so hopefully the example table makes sense.

The following data frame is what I have now:

```
> df = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),numToAdd = c(1,1,3,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,2,3,2),occurs = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))

> df
   group numToAdd occurs
1      1        1      0
2      1        1      0
3      1        3      1
4      1        2      0
5      2        4      0
6      2        2      1
7      2        1      0
8      2        3      0
9      2        2      0
10     3        1      0
11     3        2      1
12     3        1      1
13     4        2      0
14     4        3      0
15     4        2      0
```

Thus, whenever a 1 occurs within a group, I want a cumulative sum of the values from the column numToAdd, until a new group starts. This would look like the following:

```
> finalDF = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),numToAdd =    c(1,1,3,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,2,3,2),occurs = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),added = c(0,0,3,5,0,2,3,6,8,0,2,3,0,0,0))

> finalDF
   group numToAdd occurs added
1      1        1      0     0
2      1        1      0     0
3      1        3      1     3
4      1        2      0     5
5      2        4      0     0
6      2        2      1     2
7      2        1      0     3
8      2        3      0     6
9      2        2      0     8
10     3        1      0     0
11     3        2      1     2
12     3        1      1     3
13     4        2      0     0
14     4        3      0     0
15     4        2      0     0
```

Thus, the added column is 0 until a 1 occurs within the group, then accumulates the values from numToAdd until it moves to a new group, turning the added column back to 0. In group three, a value of 1 is found a second time, yet the cumulated sum continues. Additionally, in group 4, a value of 1 is never found, thus the value within the added column remains 0.

I've played around with dplyr, but can't get it to work. The following solution only outputs the total sum, and not the increasing cumulated number at each row.

```
library(dplyr)
df = 
  df  %>%
  mutate(added=ifelse(occurs == 1,cumsum(numToAdd),0)) %>%
  group_by(group)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(added= cumsum(numToAdd*cummax(occurs)))
 #      group numToAdd occurs added
 # 1      1        1      0     0
 # 2      1        1      0     0
 # 3      1        3      1     3
 # 4      1        2      0     5
 # 5      2        4      0     0
 # 6      2        2      1     2
 # 7      2        1      0     3
 # 8      2        3      0     6
 # 9      2        2      0     8
 # 10     3        1      0     0
 # 11     3        2      1     2
 # 12     3        1      1     3
 # 13     4        2      0     0
 # 14     4        3      0     0
 # 15     4        2      0     0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 i1 <-setDT(df)[, .I[(rleid(occurs) + (occurs>0))>1], group]$V1
 df[, added:=0][i1, added:=cumsum(numToAdd), by = group]
```

Or a similar option as in `dplyr`

```
 setDT(df)[,added := cumsum(numToAdd * cummax(occurs)) , by = group]
```

Comment: These approaches are the quickest and cleanest imo

Comment: @PierreLafortune  Thanks for your comments.  I remember `cummax` while trying some code golfing :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use split-apply-combine in base R with something like:

```
df$added <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) {
  y <- rep(0, nrow(x))
  pos <- cumsum(x$occurs) > 0
  y[pos] <- cumsum(x$numToAdd[pos])
  y
}))
df
#    group numToAdd occurs added
# 1      1        1      0     0
# 2      1        1      0     0
# 3      1        3      1     3
# 4      1        2      0     5
# 5      2        4      0     0
# 6      2        2      1     2
# 7      2        1      0     3
# 8      2        3      0     6
# 9      2        2      0     8
# 10     3        1      0     0
# 11     3        2      1     2
# 12     3        1      1     3
# 13     4        2      0     0
# 14     4        3      0     0
# 15     4        2      0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

To add another `base R` approach:

```
df$added <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) {
    c(x[,'occurs'][cumsum(x[,'occurs']) == 0L],
  cumsum(x[,'numToAdd'][cumsum(x[,'occurs']) != 0L]))
}))
#    group numToAdd occurs added
# 1      1        1      0     0
# 2      1        1      0     0
# 3      1        3      1     3
# 4      1        2      0     5
# 5      2        4      0     0
# 6      2        2      1     2
# 7      2        1      0     3
# 8      2        3      0     6
# 9      2        2      0     8
# 10     3        1      0     0
# 11     3        2      1     2
# 12     3        1      1     3
# 13     4        2      0     0
# 14     4        3      0     0
# 15     4        2      0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R:

```
df$added <- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$group),function(x){
  cumsum((cumsum(x$occurs) > 0) * x$numToAdd)
}))
```